# How to make Vimperator/Pentadactyl keep status line visible in full-screen mode?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, vimperator

On Mac, Pentadactyl and Vimperator automatically hide the status line (aka status bar) when you go into full-screen mode.

Is there a way to always keep the status line visible, regardless of whether the browser is in full-screen or regular mode?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to always keep the status line visible?

Yes, there is. Simply add the following command to your `~/.pentadactylrc` (or a Vimperator equivalent):

```
au Fullscreen .* :set guioptions+=s
```

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of vimperator, the command to put into `~/.vimperatorrc` is

```
au Fullscreen .* :set statuslinevisibility=visible
```